# Rails Gem: How to get a gem application layout?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to customize a Rails Gem with the default CRUD-Views.

app/views/new.html.erb:

```
<div class="wishlist">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 medium-10 large-8 small-centered columns">

      <h1><%= Spree.t(:creating_wishlist) %></h1>
      <%= form_for @wishlist do |f| %>
      <p><%= f.label :name, Spree.t(:name) %>:&nbsp;<%= f.text_field :name %></p>
      <p><%= f.check_box :is_private %>&nbsp;<%= f.label :is_private, Spree.t(:is_private) %></p>
      <%= f.submit Spree.t(:create) %>
      <% end -%>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to avoid the same div containers .wishlist .row etc. in all the other views.
How can i achieve something like:

```
# gem application layout:
<div class="wishlist">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 medium-10 large-8 small-centered columns">

      <%= yield %>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When i save it as app/views/layouts/application.html.erb and render it in the gem controller with layout 'application' then the view of the main Rails Application Layout will be overwritten.
But I just want only the Gem CRUD views to get yield.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve it with a partial that i render outside a do/end-block of the CRUD Views:

partial in app/views/base/_layout.html.erb

```
<div class="wishlist">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="hide-for-small medium-1 large-2 columns"></div>
    <div class="small-12 medium-10 large-8 small-centered columns">
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
    <div class="hide-for-small medium-1 large-2 columns"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and in my CRUD Views:

```
<%= render :layout => 'base/layout' do %>
  # content
<% end -%>
```